# Linq ForEach vs All Performance review

Tags: c#, linq

For most of the time I am using All(and returns true) instead of ForEach. Is it a good practice to use ALL instead of ForEach all the time(in case of IEnumerable), I understand All could be run on IEnumerable whereas foreach runs only on list

```
  var wells = GlobalDataModel.WellList.Where(u => u.RefProjectName == project.OldProjectName);
  if (wells.Any())
        {
            wells.All(u =>
            {
                u.RefProjectName = project.ProjectName;
                return true;
            });
        }

   var wellsList = GlobalDataModel.WellList.Where(u => u.RefProjectName == project.OldProjectName).ToList();
   wellsList.ForEach(u => u.RefProjectName = project.ProjectName);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, You're abusing the `All` method. Take a look at [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548541%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.

It should be used to determine all elements are true/false based on some condition, It is not meant to used to produce **side effects**.

`List.ForEach` is meant to be used for side effects. You may use it if you already have `List<T>` upfront. Calling `ToList` and creating new `List` just for the sake of `List.ForEach` is not worth. It adds another O(n) operation.

In short don't use `All` for side effects, `List.ForEach` is barely acceptable when you have list already. Recommended way is use loop of your choice, nothing can be better than that.

Ericlippert has something to say about [ForEach](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx), note that it is removed in ModernUI apps, may be removed in desktop version of .net too.

Comment: I want to perform some operation on Enumerable, Should I change it to list to run foreach?

Comment: @MegaMind Yes, use foreach loop. That's why it exist.

Comment: I was confused as in your answer you said, using ToList just for the sake of foreach is not worth. Can you please clear me at that point

Comment: @MegaMind, `ToList` evaluates the enumerable and creates a new `List` from it. It will have to iterate the entire enumerable while creating the list, and all this work is for nothing because all you want is to iterate the list anyway.

Comment: @MegaMind It appears to me that you're calling `.ToList()` method to create a new list, It is not that you need a list, actually you need to use `List.ForEach` method. just because `List.ForEach` method exist on `List<T>` class creating a new list. Don't do that. `ToList` method will iterate the enumerable once, then you're iterating it again in `List.ForEach` method. Is that clear?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes, that's exactly my point, just to iterate through an IEnumerable, I need to create a list. That does not feel worth it. SineLaw's code makes sense as he is not using linq foreach but normal foreach. Same question again, to perform an operation on Enumerable what should I do 1) Normal foreach or some linq operation

Comment: @MegaMind Same answer again: If you have a enumerable use foreach loop, if you have a `List<T>` already you may use `List.ForEach` but still I'd recommend foreach loop only.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Finally got it, for enumerable go for normal foreach otherwise use anything. Big thanks for being patient with me.

Answer (score 2):

If you're checking whether all elements satisfy some condition, use `All`.

But, if you need to perform some **operation** on each element, don't use `All` or any other LINQ predicate (`Where`, `Select`, `Any`, etc.), as they are meant to be used in a purely functional way. You can iterate over the elements using a `foreach .. in` loop or if you prefer with the [`List<T>.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. However as you mention it is part of `List<T>` and makes your code slightly harder to change (e.g. from list to another enumerable).

[See here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/185967) for a discussion about the "right way" to use LINQ.

---

For example, you can write your code like this:

```
foreach (var u in GlobalDataModel.WellList
                                 .Where(u => u.RefProjectName == project.OldProjectName)) 
{
    u.RefProjectName = project.ProjectName;
}
```

It's more obvious that side effects are being done. Also, this will only iterate once over the sequence, skipping the elements that don't satisfy the condition.

Comment: More readable: add another local variable which holds the query :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, possibly, it's a matter of taste. I prefer not to introduce a variable if it's being used only once - it introduces a mutable state (variable) that is never supposed to be changed.

Comment: You got a point, but stackoverlow's scrollbars says that introducing a variable will make it more readable ;)